# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid characters (CR/LF) in redirect location

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid characters (CR/LF) in redirectlocation.org.springframework.security.web.firewall.FirewalledResponse.sendRedirect(FirewalledResponse)javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i am working in spring mvc project ..when redirect ..this exception occured .

Comment: can you show your code please?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/approval")   
 public String  showApproval()  {   return  "redirect:/showdisplay?Id=1234&type=xxxxx&mode=yyyyy";}

Comment: The question lacks description and can not be beneficial for others. Please update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem ..Its working fine to me.

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/showdisplay");
            mav.addObject("Id","1234");
mav.addObject("type","xxxxx");
mav.addObject("mode","yyyy");
return mav;
```